# Django Models - function to get all objects in parent's BaseModel class

Tags: django, django-models, parent-child

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    imported_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def get_all_imported_id(self):
        all_objects = xxxxx.objects.all()
        return [i.imported_from for i in all_objects]

class Model_1(BaseModel):
....

class Model_2(BaseModel):
....
```

I want to create function "get_all_imported_id" in my BaseModel class that returns a list of values in all my present and future models. When called, e.g. Model1.get_all_imported_id() should return a list of all Models1 imported ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    # …

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    @classmethod
    def get_all_imported_id(cls):
        return cls.objects.values('imported_id', flat=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the functionality you described, you can use Django's model inheritance and create a custom manager for the BaseModel class. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
from django.db import models

class BaseModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_all_imported_id(self):
        return list(self.values_list('imported_id', flat=True))

class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    imported_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    objects = BaseModelManager()

class Model_1(BaseModel):
    # ... Model_1 fields ...

class Model_2(BaseModel):
    # ... Model_2 fields ...
```